# spring mvc controller - missing cookie named 'xyz'

Tags: spring-mvc, cookies, mapping, spring-3, optional-parameters

I have an existing controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getProduct(@PathVariable String productId){
 // code in this method does not matter
}
```

I need to enhance the existing behavior of this route by analyzing user's cookie. If user has the cookie named **xyz** I need to make a different stuff.
So I created an overloaded version of **getProduct** method by adding the second parameter  **@CookieValue("xyz")   final String xyz**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getProduct(@PathVariable String productId, @CookieValue("xyz") final String xyz){
 // make some different logic 
}
```

When I try to access this route, spring always throw an exception

```
org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException: Missing cookie named 'xyz' for method parameter type [java.lang.String]
```

Obviously the overloaded version of the method getProduct is always called.

How can I fix this bug? Is there any annotation to tell that the cookie value is optional?

Answer (score 5):

Just found that there is **required** attribute for **@CookieValue** annotation